# setRightBarButtonItems:animated: crash

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, uiresponder

I called

`[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:nil animated:YES];`

to hide the buttons during refresh operations

Sometimes I caught an exception saying

```
*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: kUINavigationBarAnimationRightViews)
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously the `rightBarButtonItems` array contained an item with a custom view - a `UISearchBar` being a `firstResponder`.

Calling the following line of code caused the crash

`[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:nil animated:YES];`

### The solution

Simply calling

`self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];`

solved the issue